# Styling an Eclipse Toolbar Using CSS

Tags: eclipse-plugin, e4

I want to style the `ToolBar` of our Eclipse application using CSS:

```
   <extension id="product" point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.products">
      <product application="org.acme.application" name="Application">
         <!-- other stuff -->
         <property name="cssTheme" value="ourtheme" />
      </product>
   </extension>

   <extension point="org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme">
      <theme basestylesheeturi="branding/theme.css"
            id="ourtheme"
            label="Our Theme">
   </extension>
```

Everything works (i.e. `background-color: COLOR-WHITE` makes the toolbar white). However I'm struggeling to find what CSS tags are allowed.

[The Eclipse GIT Repo](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.ui.git/tree/bundles/org.eclipse.ui.themes/css) has a couple of CSS files, which have the following keys for the toolbar:

```
#org-eclipse-ui-main-toolbar {
    background-image:  url(./winXPOlive.png);
    eclipse-perspective-keyline-color: #585858;
    background-color: #515658 #515658 100%;
    handle-image: none;
    color: #EBE8E4;
}
```

Or that all of them? Is there a comprehensive manual somewhere? Or is CSS styling on a trial and error base?

(In case a specific use case is required: I want to add padding to the tool-items, and / or a border of some sort.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a manual listing everything.

All the CSS properties are defined using the `org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core.propertyHandler` extension point so using the Eclipse plugin search will show you all the definitions. The majority of these are in the `org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt` plugin with a few in other plugins.

Definitions look like:

```xml
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core.propertyHandler">
  <handler
        adapter="org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.dom.ControlElement"
        composite="true"
        handler="org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.properties.css2.CSSPropertyBackgroundSWTHandler">
     <property-name
           name="background">
     </property-name>
     <property-name
           name="background-color">
     </property-name>
     <property-name
           name="background-image">
     </property-name>
  </handler>
```

`adapter` is defined by the `org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core.elementProvider` extension point, it is generally named to give a good idea of what the property applies to - any `Control` in this case.

You can also look at the `handler` class to see exactly how the properties are dealt with.